# Reverse bits program logic not clear

Tags: python, reverse, bit

I was asked to write a program of reversing bits of a given 32 bits unsigned integer.

For example, if the input is 43261596, the output should be 964176192 (binary of input is 00000010100101000001111010011100, and after reversing output becomes 00111001011110000010100101000000 whose decimal equivalent is 964176192).

I wrote the following program:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseBits(self, n: int) -> int:
        
        binary = ""
        
        for i in range(32):
            binary = binary + str(n%2)
            n = n//2
        
        return int(binary,2)
```

Upon submission, this answer was received with an alternative solution that was 'claimed to be more time ans space efficient'. Here's the alternative one:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseBits(self, n: int) -> int:
        
        if (n == 0):
            return 0
    
        result = 0
        for i in range(32):
            result <<= 1
            if ((n & 1) == 1):
                result +=1
            n >>= 1
            
        return result
```

The logic they provided was left/right shifting of bits.

I am totally clueless as to how does bit shifting to the left/right help in reversing the bits of a decimal integer. To further clarify, I myself wrote this snippet:

```
a = 9
print(a>>1,a<<1)
```

The outputs were 4 and 18 respectively(integer halved and doubled).

But how does this concept contribute to revrsing bits of an integer? And also why is this considered more time and space efficient than my solution? Please help.

Comment: Your original solution is using halving and modulo 2 operations, so you seem to have some idea how it helps?

Comment: Neither of your code examples comply with the directive "The input must be a binary string of length 32.". Please clarify, with an example, what the inut and expected output should look like

Comment: @BrutusForcus I have edited the question with input/output examples.

Comment: Another approach is to translate the bit representation to string, reverse that and parse back to decimal. Pretty short and concise: `int(f"{n:032b}"[::-1], 2)` where `n` is the input number

Comment: @bereal I do know what is % and / operators, but what I don't understand here is how is that helping in reversing bits of an integer.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I suppose int may not be valid for Python, so what's the code for Python for the same?

Comment: Why? It's a built-in function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit shifting is similar to your string concatenation, `binary = binary + str(n%2)` effectively shifts the already existing characters to the left by one position (similar to `result <<= 1`). Since for the bit shift approach, this will add a `0` at the end, they need to optionally increase the value by `1` if the last binary digit of the current `n` is `1` (`result += 1`). Then `n >>= 1` does the same as `n //= 2`.

The second approach basically requires an additional 32 bit for the `result` (at least theoretically), while the string approach will end up with a 32-character string which uses about 32 bytes. Also integer operations will likely be faster than string operations.